# aws cli gives access denied when running shell_exect

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

On the command line I can run:

aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket . --dryrun

just fine.

However, I'm trying to run it as a command in Laravel:

```
public function handle()
    {
        $command = 'aws s3 sync s3://my_bucket . --dryrun';
        shell_exec($command);
    }
```

and am getting:

> fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
> ListObjectsV2 operation: Access Denied

Why does the same command work on the command line but not within my PHP application?

Comment: When run via PHP there are likely no environment variables set, so the AWS CLI doesn't know where to autoload your credentials from. Specify the credentials file explicitly, and check the CLI docs/help/manpage for how to do it. Alternatively, there are libraries you can use to interact with the AWS APIs directly rather than going back and forth to the CLI.

Comment: Would you mind posting this as a response? Or I can answer my own question with the command I'm actually using.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice of @Sammitch, and used

> --profile my_config

where my_config was a named set of configuration parameters created using:

```
aws configure --profile my_config
```

Source: [AWS creating a named profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html)